# BotFramework: Create Suggested Actions without text attribute

Tags: node.js, botframework

I'm creating a bot in `DirectLine`. I'm trying to use `SuggestedActions` to display a suggested action and I don't want to include the `text` attribute for that. When I try to run my code without the text attribute, I see a blank message being displayed. How can I avoid that?

**My code**

```
var msg = new builder.Message(session)
            .suggestedActions(
               builder.SuggestedActions.create(
                    session, [
                         builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "disconnect", "Disconnect"),
                     ]
             ));
session.send(msg);
```

**The Output i'm getting:**

[image]

Comment: suggested actions are based on Message which wiil never send user an empty string, and which doesn't make sense. Could you share why you want this feature, maybe we can find a workaround.

Comment: I'm building an app, where the bot transfers the chat to a human agent if it can't answer a question. I want to have a "floating" disconnect button, so the agent can click on it anytime and the user is transferred back to the bot.

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding, you want a button which is shown absoluted at bottom and always display to remind your agent that he can `disconnect` conversation any time.

However, per me testing and understanding, in my opinion, there 2 points that it's maybe not a good idea to achieve this feature:

- `SuggestedAction` is based on `Messasge` in Bot framework. And basically Bot application is for conversation. So every message between user and bot renderred in different channels should always be contained in a textbox, shown like in your capture. We cannot bypass this feature.
- Per your requirements, I think you want this button should be always display unless the agent click it. But I didn't find any feature like this in Bot framework, and you may need to send this meesage additionally beside every message from bot, which is not graceful and will raise unpredictable risk.

My suggestion is that you can create a triggerAction to handle global `disconnect` requests. Refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-dialog-actions for more info.